# Clear cookies ondisabled event for chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I have this code in my chrome extension! but I would like to clear cookies on Disabled event! .Whenever an extension is disabled or uninstalled it will clear all the cookies.

In manifest.json:

```
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
"permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "https://*/",
    "http://*/"
  ]
```

In background.js:

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({domain: ".mydomain.com"}, function(cookies) {
    for(var i=0; i<cookies.length;i++) {
      console.log(cookies[i]);

      chrome.cookies.remove({url: "https://" + cookies[i].domain  + cookies[i].path, name: cookies[i].name});
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't get any event when your extension is disabled or uninstalled.

You could make cookies relatively short-lived or session cookies - that way they won't persist *far* beyond your extension's install - but by design you can't react to users disabling your extension.

If you control the domain for which cookies are being set, then you can use [`chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-setUninstallURL) to force Chrome to open a page that clears the cookies - this will cover the uninstall part, but not the disable part. There's nothing you can do for disable to clear immediately.